# Magento 2 : How to get website Url by website Id in Observer

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have multiple website in my magento 2 store.
I am creating custom code so i need to website Url by using website id, i was trying many different way but i can't get url.

```
$this->_objectManager->getWebsite(1)->getDefaultStore()->getBaseUrl();
```

i am also trying another way is :

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Linksture\ApplyCoupon\Model\ApplyCouponFactory $applycouponFactory,
    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Coupon\CollectionFactory $couponcollectionFactory
    ) {
$this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
$this->_applycouponFactory = $applycouponFactory;
$this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
$this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
$this->_couponcollectionFactory = $couponcollectionFactory;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{  
    echo $this->_storeManager->getWebsite(1)->getDefaultStore()->getBaseUrl();
}
```

In magento 1.x, using like below.

```
Mage::app()->getWebsite(1)->getDefaultStore()->getBaseUrl();
```

Answer (score 2):

suppose you have multiple websites and one website under multiple store,you get all **baseUrl**, **websiteId** and **storeId** .

```
 public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager    
        ) {
            $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        }

        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){
            $storeManager =  $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
            $websites = $storeManager->getWebsites();
            foreach($websites as $website){
                foreach($website->getStores() as $store){
                    $wedsiteId = $website->getId();
                    $storeObj = $storeManager->getStore($store);
                    $storeId = $storeObj->getId();
                    $url = $storeObj->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
                }
            }

        }
```